# Stored procedure to insert a new employee and return the newly created record (including the Id)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee
@RFC varchar(15), 
@FirstNames varchar(150), 
@LastNames varchar(150), 
@DOB datetime, 
@IdPosition bigint, 
@ReportsTo bigint, 
@IdBranch bigint, 
@Salary money
AS
INSERT INTO Employee
( 
    RFC, 
    FirstNames, 
    LastNames, 
    DOB, 
    IdPosition, 
    ReportsTo, 
    IdBranch, 
    Salary
)
VALUES(@RFC, @FirstNames, @LastNames, @DOB, @IdPosition, @ReportsTo, @IdBranch, @Salary)
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employee ORDER BY IdEmployee DESC
```

How can I do this without the SELECT TOP 1, since this could cause trouble with multiple queries at the same time with the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess This could be the easiest method .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee
@RFC varchar(15), 
@FirstNames varchar(150), 
@LastNames varchar(150), 
@DOB datetime, 
@IdPosition bigint, 
@ReportsTo bigint, 
@IdBranch bigint, 
@Salary money
AS

begin

Declare @Employee_pk bigint

INSERT INTO Employee
( 
    RFC, 
    FirstNames, 
    LastNames, 
    DOB, 
    IdPosition, 
    ReportsTo, 
    IdBranch, 
    Salary
)
VALUES(@RFC, @FirstNames, @LastNames, @DOB, @IdPosition, @ReportsTo, @IdBranch, @Salary)

set @Employee_pk=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

select * from EMPLOYEE where id=@Employee_pk


end
```

Comment: This one was indeed the fastest and better Thank you!

Comment: I was trying this also but couldn't make it work, now I know how to set the Scope_Identity

Comment: I didn't  it helped me a lot

Comment: Is it not showing the record that you are inserted.??

Comment: Yes it is, it worked perfectly
I didn't down voted you

Answer (score 1):

USE `OUTPUT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee
@RFC varchar(15), 
@FirstNames varchar(150), 
@LastNames varchar(150), 
@DOB datetime, 
@IdPosition bigint, 
@ReportsTo bigint, 
@IdBranch bigint, 
@Salary money
AS

DECLARE @INSERTEDID TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO Employee
( 
    RFC, 
    FirstNames, 
    LastNames, 
    DOB, 
    IdPosition, 
    ReportsTo, 
    IdBranch, 
    Salary
) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @INSERTEDID (ID)
VALUES(@RFC, @FirstNames, @LastNames, @DOB, @IdPosition, @ReportsTo, @IdBranch, @Salary)

SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @INSERTED_ID)
```

Comment: Wait, but I need to get all not just the ID, I need name, and branch etc..

Comment: This is the better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Use @@Identity :

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee
 @RFC varchar(15), 
 @FirstNames varchar(150), 
 @LastNames varchar(150), 
 @DOBdatetime, 
 @IdPosition bigint, 
 @ReportsTo bigint, 
 @IdBranch bigint, 
 @Salary money
 AS

 DECLARE @LastInsertedId INT = 0   

  INSERT INTO Employee
  ( 
      RFC,     FirstNames,     LastNames,     DOB,     IdPosition, 
      ReportsTo,     IdBranch,     Salary
  )
  VALUES(@RFC, @FirstNames, @LastNames, @DOB, @IdPosition, @ReportsTo,  
         @IdBranch, @Salary)

  SELECT @LastInsertedId = @@IDENTITY

  SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id = @LastInsertedId
```